# Updating nodes from multiple xml strings

Tags: c#, xml

I basically need to encrypt the data that is stored in field of a table as xml string.

I am using AES encryption. I already have the logic for encryption and decryption. All I want to do is load the xml string and update two nodes.

Basically I need to update

`<Bankaccountnumber>23232323</Bankaccountnumber>Banksortcode>232323</Banksortcode>` nodes.

I basically have around 60,000 records and want to do it efficiently using C# program. Please see the sample of the xml string below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><callvalidate><authentication><company>Bestinvest Brokers</company><username>API@bestinvest.co.uk</username><password>Pa55word67</password></authentication><sessions><session RID="0cee7f47-59b4-4fb2-a8eb-bafba9dec8ee"><data><Checksrequired><BankStandard>Yes</BankStandard><BankEnhanced>Yes</BankEnhanced><CardLive>No</CardLive><CardEnhanced>No</CardEnhanced><IDEnhanced>Yes</IDEnhanced><DeliveryFraud>No</DeliveryFraud><EmailValidate>No</EmailValidate><CreditScore>No</CreditScore><Zodiac>No</Zodiac><IPAddress>No</IPAddress></Checksrequired><Personalinformation><IndividualDetails><Title>Mr.</Title><Firstname>test</Firstname><Surname>test</Surname><Dateofbirth>1996-02-01T00:00:00</Dateofbirth><Emailaddress>ranjit.menon9@gmail.com</Emailaddress></IndividualDetails><AddressDetails><Buildingname></Buildingname><Postcode>se93qS</Postcode><Previouspostcode /></AddressDetails></Personalinformation><Bankaccountnumber>23232323</Bankaccountnumber><Banksortcode>232323</Banksortcode></data></session></sessions><application>LT-API-BEML</application></callvalidate>
```

Comment: That sample doesn't have a Bankaccountnumber or Banksortcode node!

Comment: Sorry just updated the sample

Comment: What is your C# program? Why doesn't it work? At the moment I can't see any code. Do you expect us to implement it from scatch? [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com/) may help you in such cases, but the Stack Overflow model is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument callvalidate = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> bankAccountNumbers = callvalidate.Descendants("Bankaccountnumber").ToList();
            for(int index = 0; index < bankAccountNumbers.Count; index++)
            {
                XElement bankAccountNumber = bankAccountNumbers[index];

                int accountNumber = int.Parse(bankAccountNumber.Value);
                XElement newBankAccountNumber = new XElement("Bankaccountnumber", new object[] {
                    accountNumber,
                    new XElement("Banksortcode",accountNumber)
                });
                bankAccountNumber = newBankAccountNumber;
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Please note i am reading multiple records, hence would have to loop through each xml string collection  , fetch the value and update it